# Несовместимость стандартных библиотек MS/GCC при использовании загрузчика .exe?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc

Имеется консольное приложение, которое было скомпилировано на компиляторе от Майкрософта ( с использованием `WINAPI` функций, разумеется), С++. Исходного кода и аналогов этой программы тоже нет. Дизассемблирование показывает около 3500 функций, так что полная обратная разработка займет очень много времени.

Я поставил перед собой задачу - написать универсальный загрузчик, поддерживающий несколько операционных систем (код выбирается на этапе компиляции). Пока веду работу только на Windows.

Загрузка выполняется по принципу "размести оригинальные сегменты в нужных местах, обработай таблицу импорта, вызови entry point". Для рeализации был выбран gcc (MinGW), так как он поддерживает модифицированные скрипты компоновщика, язык С.

Сегменты были расположены корректно, таблица импорта обработана корректно, точка входа вызывается, аргументы обрабатываются корректно.
Проблема заключается в том, что рано или поздно возникает ошибка R6002 (как побочный эффект), но я уверен, что проблема именно в компоновке программы (несовместимы библиотеки времени выполнения и где-то что-то проинициализировалось, а где-то нет?), а не в каких-то конкретных ошибках. Отладка произодится с помощью Qt creator, но она затруднительна, так как есть только ассемблерный листинг.

Вопрос такой: придется патчить вызовы стандартных функций, чтобы заставить загрузчик работать или можно что-нибудь придумать?

Comment: переписать wine с нуля - хорошее дело

Comment: С трудом понимаю что именно вы делаете. Вы хотите написать софтину для выполнения различных форматов бинарников в разных ОС?

Comment: Если вы считаете реализацию для конкретной программы - переписыванием wine - то да. Пока, я пробую свои силы. Впоследствии загрузчик может быть целиком встроен в другое приложение. Оно, кстати, работает по тому же принципу, отличие только в том, что использовался бинарник ELF x86 и он спокойно запускается под виндой.

Comment: Кстати, 3500 функций имеют какой общий объем в байтах? Сколько из них осталось нераспознано после применения FLIRT, если вы его применяли?

Comment: 823 кб - чистый .text сегмент. FLIRT не применял - не знаю, что это такое. Возможно, IDA что-то и делала в автоматическом режиме. Если вам чем-то поможет, то есть и именные, выделенные бирюзовым, функции.

Comment: @T-Max в IDA откройте, она часть библиотечных функций вполне может опознать. 800+ кило - конечно, многовато для реверсинга, но не думаю что реверсить нужно совсем все. Хотя в любом случае это выйдет ДОРОГО.

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я и пишу загрузчик, а не переписываю и без того отлаженный и рабочий код.

Comment: C++ — язык без бинарного стандарта. Мне кажется, что задача, которую вы перед собой поставили, вряд ли реализуема в полной общности и объёме.

Comment: А msvcrt.dll по идее программы [вообще не должны использовать](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273).

Comment: Все мы люди и можем ошибаться. Я отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Что-то я суть не могу ухватить. В конце-концов Вы хотите запустить этот бинарник в линуксе? (если хотите, чтобы человек, которому Вы отвечаете в комментарии увидел Ваш комментарий пишите @NICK)

Comment: @avp На данном этапе я решаю проблему запуска на винде, но да, итоговая цель - запустить на любой совместимой с х86 LE системе при наличии кода загрузчика.

Comment: Понятно. Сейчас какие-то relocatable неправильно модифицируются. А что Вы будете делать с отсутствующими (.so (виндовые .dll)) в лине?

Comment: Я почитал о [R6002 тут](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/234747-error-runtime-error-r6002-floating-point-support-not-loaded.html) и в др. местах. Это же просто мистика какая-то. И как люди в винде программят?

Comment: @avp Нормально программят. Это я в дебри лезу. Библиотечные функции можно заменить заглушками или схожими по функционалу. Но опять же, решаю по одной проблеме за раз.

Comment: Я просто когда-то задумывался над подобной задачкой. Немного по другому, имеем загрузочный модуль, сделанный gcc не важно в какой ОС. Некая программа переводит его в native и он готов для использования в заданной системе. По сути заткнулся на том, как автоматизировать перенос системных библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку программа печатала

```
runtime error R6002
- floating point support not loaded
```

я решил выяснить, из-за чего появляется эта ошибка. И нашёл вот что ("стек вызовов"):

```
__NMSG_WRITE
_amsg_exit(2) <= 2 - код ошибки (соответствует R6002)
_fptrap
```

Функция `_fptrap` использовалась действительно как заглушка аж 10 раз в массиве из 10 функторов. Интересным является то, что вызваться эта функция не могла, т.к. до такого вызова происходила безусловная перезапись этих функторов на другие:

```
void __cdecl _cfltcvt_init_0()
{
  off_519200 = _cfltcvt;      // Все эти off_* были инициализированы
  off_519204 = sub_4B91DF;    // функтором _fptrap.
  off_519208 = _fassign;
  off_51920C = _forcdecpt;
  off_519210 = _positive;
  off_519214 = _cfltcvt;
  off_519218 = _cfltcvt_l;
  off_51921C = _fassign_l;
  off_519220 = _cropzeros_l;
  off_519224 = _forcdecpt_l;
}
```

Я изменил эту заглушку на обычный `nullsub`, полёт нормальный. Однако остаётся чувство, что где-то меня обманывают.